# how to write this particular regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

What is the regex I need to use if I

Need to select the "10" in player list and not the "10" from group

```
{"group":"10","player":["12","15","13","10","1"]}
```

Sorry I should have given a little more on the programming scope

The json string is supposed to be treated as a string and not json parsed because I need to use query in mysql to select rows that match this criteria..

for example, in the above example...

`Select * from team Where jsondata=(Something to the effect that "10" can be found in player list but will ignore if "10" is found only in group)`

If i use:

```
Select * from team Where jsondata LIKE'%"10"%'
```

then obviously it would be wrong because if the data was `{"group":"10","player":[]}` it would still qualify

i want to run a php command like `preg_match` to match the "10" form the player list if found

Thanks for those who have replied so far

Comment: What language, and why aren't you using a JSON parser? And what have you tried?

Comment: Favorite regex testing tool: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: That's straight up JSON, you need to use the right tool for the job. Use a JSON parser in the language of your choice and forget about the Regex.

Comment: Saw your edit. Are you saying that it won't always be JSON? 'Cuz you can still parse the JSON using PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: yes you should be checking the checkbox. 43% is quite low.

Comment: oh i do that all the time, if it was solved. would u mind having a look at my edit again? i wrote my intention wrongly and its been rewritten again

Comment: Yeah I know what you're trying to do, but regex is the wrong tool. I don't know enough about php, but I know in .NET I can create an object out of a JSON string, and that object can be queryable. Then I can query that object for whatever data I need. I would *assume* that you can create queryable objects in php as well.

Comment: @user6890 Did you notice my updated answer? It should be solvable with pure MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked for a regular expression. However, if the string will always be a Python dict, then how about:

```
str = "{\"group\":\"10\",\"player\":[\"12\",\"15\",\"13\",\"10\",\"1\"]}"

"10" in eval( str )["player"]
```

This would test whether the string `"10"` exists for the list in the `"player"` key. You might want something slightly different. **The point being, if the data will always be a serialized Python data structure, you'll be able to work with this data much more naturally as a Python data structure.**

Note, since I was typing the string manually I had to escape the `"`. If you were reading this string from a file you wouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try somenthing like this: `"player":\[.*"(10)"` or `"player":\[("\d+",)*?"(10)"`

Depends on, how strictly you like it.

In MySQL you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM team WHERE jsondata REGEXP '"player":.*"10"'
```

Comment: The OP didn't say whether or not the `10` would ever be a `9` or a `123`. If that number ever changes.... uh oh.

Comment: i tried your solution on http://www.regextester.com/ where i paste your solution and my string as the test.. but it highlightedmore than "10" it got "player":["12","15","13","10"

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: Sorry, but I can't get you. Of course the OP is free to exchange the `10` int the regex with whatever number he/she needs.

Comment: @splash all I meant was that if the number is dynamic in any way, then a hardcoded regex with the number 10 would not be sufficient.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Surely the OP is intelligent enough to understand that a hardcoded value can be replaced with a variable?